# Xamarin Forms control where I can show HTML formated text

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm new in Xamarin and I try to show a HTML text in a Xamarin Form control.

For example, if I have the following HTML text:

```
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li></ul>
```

It should show the following result in the Xamarin app:

- First
- Second

Is there a control for that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

[**WebView**](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithWebview/):

You can use WebView to open an local HTML file to display it.

```
webviewjava.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
webviewjava.Source = "index.html";
```

**** index.html is your local HTML file.*

[**HtmlWebViewSource**](http://HtmlWebViewSource:):
Or If you want to present a string of HTML defined dynamically in code, you'll need to create an instance of **HtmlWebViewSource**:

```
var browser = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
  <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
  <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
  </body></html>";
browser.Source = htmlSource;
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i dont want to load it from a file. I have it as string, which looks like "<ul><li>Frist</li><li>Second</li></ul>"

Comment: I have edited my answer, I think HtmlWebViewSource is more suitable for you