# display html formatted data xamarin forms

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

I am using webview to display html formatted data that is coming from database. i have tried implementing the HtmlWebViewSource to display the data but it is not displaying. Here is what i have implemented.

```
<WebView VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <WebView.Source>
                        <HtmlWebViewSource x:Name="surveyInstruction"/>
                    </WebView.Source>
                </WebView>
```

.cs

```
surveyInstruction.Html = result[1][i].vchar_Instruction;
```

This is what i am getting from database

```
Question<font size="4"><b> Instruction</b></font>
```

i referred this post as well
[Xamarin Forms control where I can show HTML formated text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776370/xamarin-forms-control-where-i-can-show-html-formated-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using? I remember there were some issues like [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21699) one.

I'm using the WebView as follows (with binding) and that works fine for me.

```
    <WebView
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <WebView.Source>
            <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding PrivacyPolicyAsHtml}" />
        </WebView.Source>
    </WebView>
```

The `PrivacyPolicyAsHtml` property exists in the View Model and is assigned there.

Answer (score 0):

Change VerticalOptions from "Fill" to "FillAndExpand", you should able to see the WebView or set the height for the WebView based on the requirements.